# How to use JTransforms library with Processing 3+

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to install the library for JTransforms. I've downloaded the .jar file from here: https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

The download I have is the binary with dependencies: JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar

I changed the name to jtransforms.jar and copied the file into the libraries/jtransforms/library folder.

/sketchfolder/libraries/jtransforms/library/jtransforms.jar

However my sketch will not compile. My Processing sketch code:

```
import jtranforms.*;

void setup()
{     

}

void draw()
{      

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Console shows:

> No library found for jtranforms Libraries must be installed in a
>   folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply **drag the `JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar` file directly onto the Processing editor**.

This will automatically put the jar file in the correct place, and you'll be able to use the jar in your sketch.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working! 
Turns out my import line was incorrect. I changed the name of the file to jtransforms.jar and dragged it over the Processing window where my script was open. This copies it to the /skecthfolder/code folder. I changed my import line to this and it works now:

import org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;

(was: import transforms.*;   )

Sometimes it helps to sleep on it! What seemed impossible last night was a breeze this morning.